# Between in createdCriteria not works

Tags: java, grails, groovy, criteriaquery

I have a very strange problem. I create 3 entities with the following data:

```
CCB ccb1 = new Ccb(1)
CCB ccb2 = new Ccb(2)
CCB ccb3 = new Ccb(3)
```

Where the parameter (Long) is the object id.

Then, when wanting to create a list with the between clause, it is created with size = 0:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                between("id", 1, 5)
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

I've tried this alternative and it doesn't work either:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                between("id", "1", "5")
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

The incredible thing is that if I replace the between with the eq:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                eq("id", 2)
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

Now the list returns me the element with id 2!
I can't understand where is the error.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Config of DataSource.groovy:

```
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }
```

Comment: I know you have asserted that the type isn't the issue, so I deleted the answer, but I encourage you to evaluate that in your app.  At https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/b9f8c69e60300b02037dc8341d3057bf0016b8c3/grails-datastore-gorm-test/src/test/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/QueryAssociationSpec.groovy#L118-L123 you can see a unit test that deals with that in the same way as the code I showed you at https://github.com/jeffbrown/zottoslgormbug/blob/6f968e6809df57f8bc2edfd5fb58cbb763e6a9df/grails-app/services/zottoslgormbug/CcbService.groovy#L9-L16.  Good luck!

Comment: The examples you used at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12381 look correct with respect to the types being passed to the `between` method.  The code in your question here does not.  In particular, I would expect `between("id", 1, 5)` to work if it is changed to `between("id", 1l, 5l)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After run different tests, I came to the conclusion that it is a bug in Grails when using the H2 storage. With SQL it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        Ccb.createCriteria().list {
            between("id", 1l, 5l)
            projections {
                property('id')
            }
        }
```

or:

```
        Ccb.createCriteria().list {
            and{
                between("id", 1l, 5l)
            }
            projections {
                property('id')
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you stream the list and filter by ID?

`def list = foolist.stream().filter(f -> f.getId() > 0 && f.getId() < 4).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Groovy don't accept that sintax

Comment: yes it can, I wrote it in groovy before sending it here. maybe you forgot the import. import java.util.stream.Collectors

Comment: But it is still not useful to me, because I have to filter from the database, and your solution already has a previous list